Force excerted on 2 objects travelling with same acceleration
Suppose two objects A and B are travelling on a smooth surface (in a linear path) with the same acceleration. B is behind A and having contact with A.  (Both A and B have separate unbalanced forces acting on them to accelerate them). Supposing the velocities of the two objects are the same in any given moment, can object B apply a force on A?

My next problem is, say we have a trolley on a smooth surface. Can we keep a wooden block in vertical equilibrium, touching the outer wall of the trolley (which have friction) by balancing the weight of the block only by the frictional force exerted by the trolley wall on the block, if we are accelerating the trolley?
The thing I have difficulty in understanding is, in order to have friction, there should be a perpendicular force exerted by the block. The only way there can be a perpendicular force is the force applied by the trolley wall which comes from the unbalanced force acting to accelerate the trolley (ignore air resistance). But since both the trolley and the block are moving with the same acceleration, is it possible to exert such a force?


You need to provide information on the forc(s) responsible for accelerating A and B

Voting to reopen. The question does focus on one problem.

@BobD I edited the question providing that information. I am talking about an instance where both A and B have separate unbalanced forced acting on them, to accelerate them.

@YaraTry I'm having difficulty visualizing what you mean by "separate unbalanced forces acting on them"

@BobD I have added diagrams showing the situations. Hope that helps.


Supposing the velocities of the two objects are the same in any given
moment, can object B apply a force on A?

The short answer is yes and a set scales between the two blocks would measure this force.

In this first image, the acceleration is given by $a = (F_1+F_2)/(M_B+M_A)$. For the objects to remain in contact, $F_2/M_A$ has to be less than or equal to $F_1/M_B$. The force exerted by B on A works out as $F_{BA} = F_1 - M_B \ a$. This is the force that would be indicated by some scales placed between block B and block A. Note: We could place a rod between A and B that incorporates a balance device that can measure both both compression and tension. Now the two blocks will maintain the same acceleration even when $F_2/M_A$ is greater than $F_1/M_B$ but in that case the balance would indicate a tension force instead of a compression force that exists when $F_2/M_A$ is less than $F_1/M_B$

This second diagram is initially best analysed from the point of view of an accelerating observer riding on the front of the trolley. If they drop a ball they see it fall diagonally instead of straight down. To them the gravitational field appears to be diagonal as per the purple vector. This diagonal gravitational field has a horizontal component (red vector) acting in the opposite direction to F and normal to the vertical front surface of the trolley. If the trolley has mass $M_B$ and the block on the front has mass $M_A$ then the magnitude of this force is given by the equation I gave above for $F_{BA}$ and since R is the reaction to this force then R has the same magnitude as $F_{BA}$ but in the opposite direction. Scales placed between the block and the trolley would measure this reaction force. If $\mu$ is the coefficient of static friction for the vertical surface, then if $\mu F_{BA}$ is greater than W, the block will not slide downwards. A horizontally inertial observer standing on the ground watching the trolley and block system accelerating to the right, will not see the fictitious forces represented by the red and purple vectors.

So for a horizontally inertial observer standing on the ground, what
causes the reaction force for R? – Yara Try

Consider a version of Einstein's space elevator thought experiment which is basically a 'vertical' version of your trolley. Initially we have an inertial elevator floating around in flat space. There is ball floating around near the 'top' of the elevator. There is also a table on the 'bottom' of the elevator that has a set of scales on top of it and a large mass on top of the scales. Now a rocket attached to the elevator accelerates it 'upwards'.  To an inertial observer outside the elevator who is at rest with the ball, sees the elevator accelerating towards the ball rather than the ball accelerating towards to the base. He does not see anything resembling a gravitational force acting 'downwards'. He also sees the table bend under the weight of the mass sitting on it and a positive force indicated on the scales. The bent table top has a tension in it and a component of this tension is directed upwards and acts of the large mass accelerating the mass 'upwards' with the elevator. The large mass has inertia and it resists acceleration. The tension on the table top provides the reaction force to change the momentum of the large mass, since one definition of force is change of momentum per unit time. To the inertial observer, the tension in the table top is not a reaction force because from their point of view there is 'gravitational' force to react to. To them, the force acting on the large mass comes from the force provided by the rocket accelerating the elevator.

Does it  come from the force F acting
on the trolley to accelerate it?

Yes, just like the force acting on the table top mass comes from the rocket. It is easy to see that this force exerted by the trolley (B) on the block on the front (A) comes from the force accelerating the trolley in the equation I gave at the top ($F_{BA} = F - M_B \ a$) and this is equal in magnitude to R. $F_{BA}$ is the difference between the force F and the force required to accelerate the trolley ($M_B \ a$).  If we need a given force to provide a given acceleration to the trolley when there is no mass A on the front, we need a larger force to provide the same acceleration to the trolley with mass A attached. The force $F_{BA}$ is effectively the excess force that is not being used to accelerate the trolley only.

For the objects to remain in contact, F2 has to be less than F1. It is not compulsory right? because if they have the same force and same acceleration, they can still barely stay in contact?
So for a horizontally inertial observer standing on the ground, what causes the reaction force for R ? Does it come from the force F acting on the trolley to accelerate it? Because if there is no such force, then there is no friction to keep the block in vertical equilibrium.

@YaraTry You are correct. I should have said less than or equal to.  I also assumed that mass A is the same as B but that does not necessarily have to the case so I have edited that sentence accordingly. I have also added a section at the end to address the issues of what the inertial observer sees and where R comes from.

HINTS:
In the first example since you state the the velocities of A and B are the same at any given moment, they must always be in contact. They only way that can be assured is if they are physically "attached", since there may be some combinations of the magnitudes of the forces and masses which would allow them to separate.
Assuming they do remain in contact you can apply Newton's second law to the combination of A and B which will give you the acceleration of the combination (which is the same as that for each block) as a function of the total mass and the net applied force. Then you can do a free body diagram of A and B alone with each exerting an equal and opposite force upon one another per Newton's third law. From that you can calculate the force that B exerts upon A, which is equal and opposite to the force A exerts upon B.
In the second example the block will stay in place as long as $W$ does not exceed the maximum possible static friction force of $\mu_{s}R$ where $R$ is the normal force that the trolley exerts on the block. You can calculate that force the same way as you calculated the force that B exerts upon A, i.e., by first applying Newton's second law to the combination of the trolley and block.
Hope this helps.

Resolve the question by drawing the free-body diagram for both blocks. We have $a_A=\sum F_A /m_A = a_B=\sum F_B /m_B$because the acceleration is the same.
You will find that the answer is trivial. If there is a nonzero force acting on B from A and a 3rd Law conjugate reaction force, then there is such a force. If there is not, then there is not. Both conditions are possible.
Consider if we have a string connecting two rocks. We hold one rock above the other with the string slack (zero tension), and we drop them both at the same time. The tension force in the string stays zero.

So if I am understanding correctly, If the masses of the objects are the same and the acceleration is same and the external force acting on the objects are the same, then there is no force applied by B on A. But if the force acting on A is not sufficient to provide its acceleration, then there is a force applied by B, on A.
Consider if we have a string connecting two rocks... But if we hold rocks without a string connecting them, and drop them at the same time, then there is no force applied by one rock on the other right?

@YaraTry with or without a string, and regardless of the masses, there is no force applied by one rock on the other if we drop them at the same time and we didn't start with a force between them.
